# Remove item after crafting

Tags: xna, c#

I'm having one last problem with my crafting system. Say an item takes 2 rocks, 1 twig, and 1 vine. When I craft the item, only 1 of each item is removed instead of the correct amount of items related to the crafting recipe.

```
foreach (ItemRecipe recipe in player.PlayerCraftingSystem.CraftingList)
{
    if (recipe.Name == item.ItemName)
    {
        var commonItems = recipe.Items.Intersect(player.PlayerInventory.Items, new ListComparer()).ToList();

        var nameMatches = player.PlayerInventory.Items.Where(x => commonItems.Any(y => y.ItemName == x.ItemName));

        foreach (var match in nameMatches)
        {
            match.ItemCount--;
                if (match.ItemCount == 0)
                    match.ItemName = "empty";
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is wrong because -- will only take away one item, but I am having trouble with ideas of how to remove the correct amount of items. Does anyone have any ideas? I was thinking looping through the items being removed and using a while loop to keep removing items until it was correct, but I tried that and it froze up the game.

The item variable is the item being crafted.

Edit:

I tried adding a loop like this, but it doesn't work. It removes too many items

```
foreach (var match in nameMatches)
{
    foreach(Item itemCount in recipe.Items)
    {
        match.ItemCount -= itemCount.ItemCount;
        if (match.ItemCount == 0)
            match.ItemName = "empty";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the first line inside the foreach for the matches, you're reducing the item by 1. Without knowing your item/recipe structure I can offer this. Your recipe should know the quantity of each item it needs. So when it makes a match it should be doing something along the lines of this.

```
match.ItemCount -= recipe.ItemQuantity(match).
```

This way the recipe controls how much of them item is removed. If you want to change the amount of an ingrediant later, you can modify the number on the recipe and be done.

Edit in response to your edit.

Look at that loop closely. You're looping over each match.ItemCount for as many items are in the recipe, for each match. You don't need that inner loop. Just a similar line to the one above. Your foreach would look like this.

```
 foreach (var match in nameMatches)
 {
      match.ItemCount -= receipt.ItemQuantityFor(match);
      if (match.ItemCount == 0)
           match.ItemName = "empty";
 }
```

Comment: Each recipe contains a list of items, and each item in that list has an ItemCount variable that determines how many of each item is needed. So I would need to loop through each item in that recipe and remove the ItemCount from each item?

Comment: It might be more beneficial to store the recipe items as a key value pair, a dictionary would be a good use. Such as, Dictionary<ItemType, int>. This way you do no looping, just access the dictionary with the item as a key and it'll return the quantity it needs.

Comment: I've thought about that but then I'd have to rewrite my whole crafting system :P

Comment: If you added a method on your recipe to return the quantity for the passed in match, you'd be set, as shown in my answer above. If you're having to loop everywhere in the crafting system for items on a recipe, it may be more beneficial in the long run to refactor them out.

Comment: You should change that `==` when you check if it's 0 to `<=` and set it to 0 if it matches. That way you can't get negative items.